# Button remains active when no values are entered in textfield

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on a page where i want to disable the submit button till all values are entered in the textbox, but when the page loads the submit button is already active

```
.directive('passwordVerify', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
                if (scope.confirm_password === scope.user_password) {
                    scope.pw.confirm_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', true);
                    scope.pw.user_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', true);
                } else if (scope.confirm_password !== scope.user_password) {
                    scope.pw.confirm_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', false);
                    scope.pw.user_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', false);
                }
            });
        }
     };
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="list">
<form id="create" name="pw" method="post">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="kojobaah" ng-model="username" required>
</label>

   <label for="password">New Password
    <input type="password" name="user_password" ng-model="user_password" ng-required="confirm_password && !user-password" password-verify="confirm_pasword">
    <p ng-show="pw.user_password.$error.passwordVerify">Passwords do not match</p>
    <p ng-show="pw.user_password.$error.required">This field is required</p>
  </label>
</p>
 <p>
  <label for="password">Confirm Password
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" ng-model="confirm_password" ng-required="user_password && !confirm_password" password-verify="user_password"> 
    <p ng-show="pw.confirm_password.$error.passwordVerify">Passwords do not match</p>
    <p ng-show="pw.confirm_password.$error.required">This field is required</p>
  </label>
  <br />
  <p align="center"><button ng-disabled="create.$invalid" class="button button-balanced" ng-click="register()">Create Account</button></p>  
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
<button ng-disabled="pw.$invalid" class="button button-balanced" 
                ng-click="register()">Create Account</button>
```

`create.$invalid` change to `pw.$invalid`

Use name `form` and not `id`

Comment: i used the form name and its working but what i've noticed it when user inputs just the username the button comes alive

Comment: @user6579134 well, I think its an other question. anyways this is an answer

Comment: @user6579134 pls post Plunkr with your problem, hope ill find out the time

Answer (score 0):

not sure where it would go exactly, but here's what I found, it disables the submit button:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;
```

It might have to be "tweaked" to work with your code to be active once all the values are entered. Not sure if this helps